# How to get Information from ping federate open Token

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, pingfederate

SP aunticated the request from the IDP and redirected the request to my(Ex: Employee application) application and It's just containing openToken In form data. How can I get the Information from openToken and logon and logout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the OpenToken Guide for Java Dev -

https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/integrations/page/opp1563995022670.html

Here's KB Article. -

https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/How-do-I-view-the-contents-of-an-OpenToken